# Uncaught TypeError: d3.schemeCategory20 is not a function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new in d3js and all the javascript-world too. In my html-file I simply import the script like that:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

By trying to use following:

```
var ordinalColorScale = d3.schemeCategory20();
```

I get the exception

> Uncaught TypeError: d3.schemeCategory20 is not a function at
>   index.html:48

Do I need any other d3js module, which has to be imported? Or what could have caused the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`d3.schemeCategory20` is neither a scale nor a function. It is just an **array** of colours. According to the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#schemeCategory20), it is...

> An array of twenty categorical colors represented as RGB hexadecimal strings.

The same API says:

> These color schemes are designed to work with d3.scaleOrdinal.

Therefore, you have to pass it to an ordinal scale as its range, like this:

```
var myScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .range(d3.schemeCategory20)
```

Which is the same of:

```
    var myScale = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20)
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var scale = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

d3.select("body").selectAll(null)
  .data(d3.range(20))
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .style("background-color", function(d){ return scale(d)})
```

```css
div {
  min-height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 9):

(v5)
D3 no longer provides the d3.schemeCategory20* categorical color schemes. These twenty-color schemes were flawed because their grouped design could falsely imply relationships in the data: a shared hue can imply that the encoded data are part of a group (a super-category), while relative lightness can imply order. Instead, D3 now includes d3-scale-chromatic, which implements excellent schemes from ColorBrewer, including categorical, diverging, sequential single-hue and sequential multi-hue schemes. These schemes are available in both discrete and continuous variants.

https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md

Answer (score 6):

For d3 v4. You can use like as

```
   var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20c);
                     or
    var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
      .range(["red", "green", "blue", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);
```

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who is looking for it in future d3 versions and also something to consider when using this color scheme. Changes in D3 5.0:

> D3 no longer provides the d3.schemeCategory20* categorical color
>   schemes. These twenty-color schemes were flawed because their grouped
>   design could falsely imply relationships in the data: a shared hue can
>   imply that the encoded data are part of a group (a super-category),
>   while relative lightness can imply order

from  [d3/CHANGES.md](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md)

Answer (score 1):

`d3.schemeCategory20` it is exactly not a function. It is an array of default colors. You should pass this array to your scale function.

```js
console.log('d3.schemeCategory20 ==> ', d3.schemeCategory20);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.11.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```