# d3 pie chart all black fill, d3.schemeCategory20c not being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

Since this is getting marked as a duplicate let me clarify my problem is **not** that I am getting a *Uncaught TypeError: d3.schemeCategory20* error like the [post that is suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47052915/uncaught-typeerror-d3-schemecategory20-is-not-a-function) in fact if you look at my code and that one I am making the call the same way as the accepted answer.
If read my issue my chart is fill colors are all black, *MY ISSUE* is that `d3.schemeCategory20c` array doesn't seems to be called at all. I have no errors I have unexpected output by the method.

I'm going through **Barrett Clark**'s *Data Visualization Toolkit* book, first chapter. I have updated the code to reflect the changes in d3 *v4* but my pie chart renders with one color here is my scaleOrdinal assignment

```
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20c);
```

Here's the json call:

```
$.getJSON('/residential/data', function(data) {
    totals = data.totals;
    var g = svg.selectAll('.arc').data(pie(d3.keys(totals))).enter()
      .append('g').attr('class', 'arc');

    g.append('path').attr('d', arc).style('fill', function(d) { return color(d.data); });

    g.append('text').attr('transform',
      function(d) { return 'translate('+ arc.centroid(d) +')'; }).attr('dy', '.35em')
      .style('text-anchor', 'middle').text(function(d) { return d.data; });
  });
```

This renders a great pie chart with every slice filled in black, I've tried reading the docs but can't seem to find this implementation. I've culled from other tuts that this should work but it doesn't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught TypeError: d3.schemeCategory20 is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47052915/uncaught-typeerror-d3-schemecategory20-is-not-a-function)

Comment: not a duplicate at all, if you look at my `color` assignment I am passing the   `d3.schemeCategory20c` as an argument in the `d3.scaleOrdinal` the same as the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47052915/uncaught-typeerror-d3-schemecategory20-is-not-a-function) you linked to. I don't get an Uncaught TypeErrror, the issue with mine is the colors of the pie chart are all black, none of the `d3.schemeCategory20c` colors are being used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My answer was found in the [Changes in D3 5.0](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#changes-in-d3-50) doc.

> D3 no longer provides the d3.schemeCategory20* categorical color schemes. These twenty-color schemes were flawed because their grouped design could falsely imply relationships in the data: a shared hue can imply that the encoded data are part of a group (a super-category), while relative lightness can imply order. Instead, D3 now includes d3-scale-chromatic, which implements excellent schemes from ColorBrewer, including categorical, diverging, sequential single-hue and sequential multi-hue schemes. These schemes are available in both discrete and continuous variants.

I was searching for issues with *d3.schemeCategory20c* so I kept getting old posts, this morning when I console'd *d3.schemeCategory20c* (something I should've did a while ago) and found it to be undefined. I figured it out.